# WebService RequestSoapContext property not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wse

I have a asp.net website in visual studio 2013. I added a webservice. I need to send authentication parameter (username and password) as SOAP header. But it cannot find the property RequestSoapContext.

I added using Microsoft.Web.Services3; in my code.

```
CCWS.Service proxy = new CCWS.Service();
UsernameToken userToken = new UsernameToken("", "", PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
proxy.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);
```

Some forum says to change reference type in reference.cs file. But I cannot find any such file in my solution.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 9):

This question is rather old but after searching around, it appears the solution is to hand modify the generated proxy code to inherit from `Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol` not `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol`.

Comment: Here is the Microsoft [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) that describes this. Especially this is important: ***"...the proxy class derives from SoapHttpClientProtocol by default. To use the functionality of the WSE, change the class that the proxy class derives from to WebServicesClientProtocol."***

Comment: Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesClientProtocol also worked for me Iin case you can't add v3)

Answer (score 1):

Generate Code Using WseWsdl3.exe
Locate the WseWsdl3.exe downloaded as part of wse 3.0 and execute the following command:
C:\samples\wse>WseWsdl3.exe C:\samples\wse\us.wsdl /out:c:\samples\wse\myProxyClass.cs /protocol:SOAP /type:webClient

I guess this may help you.